# remove library import prints from terminal R script run

Tags: r, command-line

When I run a R script from terminal with the Rscript --file command, I get all the print statements of the library imports. How can I tell the terminal or R to ignore those prints? I want to just run the print() statement at the end of my file, which tells me that the program worked correctly. I have tried --slave --no-save --verbose, but none of them seem to work.

I want to achieve this since I want to run an .R script inside my python code.

Thanks in advance!

Example output of terminal:

```
...Latestcode.R'
running
  '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/bin/R --slave --no-restore --slave --no-save --file=/Users/../Latestcode.R'


Attaching package: ‘arules’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    abbreviate, write

Registered S3 method overwritten by 'seriation':
  method         from 
  reorder.hclust gclus

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
```

Comment: check `suppressPackageStartupMessages()`

Comment: ah great suggestion, i got it to work with suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library("nameofpackage"))), thanks!